# BizTalk - delimited flat file validation

Tags: schema, biztalk

I have a schema for a semicolon-delimited flat file. The schema has 2 mandatory fields (minOccurs=1), and 2 optional fields (minOccurs=0). When I use a file with 2, 3 or 4 fields (ie "var1;var2" or "var1;var2;;var4") they work as expected. However, when I use a file that has a 5th field (ie "var1;var2;;var4;invalidvar5"), rather than BizTalk throwing an input validation error, it's just assuming that that extra field is part of the value for field 4, so it parses in the resulting XML to

```
<var4>var4;invalidvar5</var4>
```

Is there a way, without resorting to pipeline components, but just using settings in the schema, to have it realize that a wrong number of fields was supplied, and so the file is invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that is a know issue with the Flat File parser.  To get it to throw a validation error you need to add field level validation.

Comment: The other option is to add a repeating optional field at the end, so it will at least parse the other fields correctly.